# How does python append to list work?

Tags: python, list, append

I came across an issue in python appending to a list. The code I implemented was:

```
a=[1,2]
b=[3,4]
a.append(b)
b.append(5)
print a
print b
```

My understanding of python append was that the expected output of this code would be:

Expected Output

```
a=[1,2,[3,4]]
b=[3,4,5]
```

But the actual output is something different.
Actual Output

```
a=[1,2,[3,4,5]]
b=[3,4,5]
```

I just want to know why this happened.

Since I appended the list `b` to `a`, before appending `5` to `b`, list `a` should have `[1,2,[3,4]]`

Answer (score 11):

Python names are [*references*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), and appending to a list appends a reference to the same object.

In other words, you did not append a copy of the `b` list. The `a` list and the name `b` share a reference to one and the same object:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a[-1] is b  # is tests if two references point to the same object
True
>>> id(a[-1]), id(b)  # id produces a unique number per object
(4595716320, 4595716320)
```

If you expected to add a copy of the `b` list to `a`, do so explicitly:

```
a.append(b[:])
```

or

```
a.append(list(b))
```

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: 'Python names are references, and appending to a list appends a reference to the same object.' - really important